# MVC3 Buddy Classes, ViewModels and Validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, data-annotations, buddy-class

I'm currently working on my first MVC project which is nothing more than a glorified blog for my own learning purposes.  I started out with a database-first approach as I had no idea code-first even existed at that point.  That's left me with some confusion as to how I should be handling validation.

I have an `Articles` table in the database which has a corresponding `Article` class which has been generated for me by EF.  I also have an `ArticleViewModel` class which has a matching property for each of the properties in `Article`.  Whilst I have simple CRUD operations working, they are currently using a strongly-typed `Article` model instead of `ArticleViewModel` and there is no data validation taking place.

After doing some research today to evaluate my options, I've found the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700464/asp-mvc3-database-first) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797312/ef-model-first-or-code-first-approach) and [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) blog post.  So it looks as though I can apply the `MetadataType` attribute to the EF generated classes and put my validation there, but I keep reading that buddy classes containing validation are bad practice.  I have no idea why that is, but if that's the case, would that mean I should ignore buddy classes and be doing something like the following?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ArticleViewModel))]
public partial class Article
{
    public Article(ArticleViewModel avm)
    {
        // Copy the properties from the ArticleViewModel into an Article.
    }
}
```

Then applying DataAnnotations to the ArticleViewModel as necessary and updating my controllers/views to use `ArticleViewModel`?

Thanks in advance for any input. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I've recently learned of this approach! and it is a good practice, as long as you don't mind the additional code involved. See [Where do you put your validation in asp.net mvc 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553380/where-do-you-put-your-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3/6553406#6553406) for more details and the accepted answer for a code example.

Comment: Are there any performance implications if using a complex table with foreign keys as a model in a view and submitting that view back for processing? Usually I created Models used on views only, then sent/laoded that model to/from my data layer and transformed it as appropriate. I learnt of this recently but upon inspection the model holds EVERYTHING about LINQ2SQL and all the drilled down tables...? Will 1000 page views a minute be worse of using this practice?